# Docker-compose with Two Kafka Clusters - For Dev Machine

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

In production I will have two sites that each has a Kafka cluster and Postgres instance.
I would like to simulate that and create on my Dev machine two Kafka "clusters" each with a single broker and two Postgres instances.  Each Kafka "cluster" is going to run a source connector which will copy data to the other site.  The docker-compose below has two Postgres instances, but only one Kafka + source connector.  What do I need to duplicate/change to create a second Kafka cluster with another source connector?

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
    networks:
      - syncNetwork   

  postgres12x_nms:
    image: "postgres:12.4"
    container_name: "pg12x_nms"
    ports:
      - "5430:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "n_db"
    volumes: 
      - vpg_nms:/var/lib/postgresql/data_nms
      - ./schema_nms.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema_nms.sql      
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      
      
  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    links:
      - postgres12x_nms      
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      


  postgres12x_mgr:
    image: "postgres:12.4"
    container_name: "pg12x_mgr"
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "n_db"
    volumes: 
      - vpg_mgr:/var/lib/postgresql/data_mgr
      - ./schema_mgr.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema_mgr.sql      
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      
      
  



  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt cjmatta/kafka-connect-irc:5.0.0
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
         echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on $$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME"
         while [ $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://$$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:$$CONNECT_REST_PORT/connectors) -ne 200 ] ; do 
           echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://$$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:$$CONNECT_REST_PORT/connectors) " (waiting for 200)"
           sleep 5 
           echo "Still waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on $$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME"
         done
         echo "Completed - Still waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on $$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME"
         nc -vz $$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME $$CONNECT_REST_PORT
         echo "Waiting for Schema Registry to start listening on schema-registry:8081"
         while [ $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://schema-registry:8081) -eq 000 ] ; do 
           echo -e $$(date) " Schema Registry listener HTTP state: " $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://schema-registry:8081) " (waiting for != 000)"
           sleep 5 
           echo "Still waiting for Schema Registry to start listening on schema-registry:8081"
         done
         echo "Completed - Still waiting for Schema Registry to start listening on schema-registry:8081"
         #
         echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Kafka Connect JDBC Sink"
         curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
            "name":"source_connector_cdc", 
            "config": {
                "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.attempts": "1000000",
                "connection.backoff.ms": "5000",
                "tasks.max":"1",
                "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://pg12x_nms:5432/n_db?user=postgres&password=postgres",                           
                "mode":"timestamp",
                "timestamp.column.name":"updated",
                "table.types":"VIEW",
                "table.whitelist":"hub_elements_v",
                "topic.prefix":"cdc_",
                "poll.interval.ms":"10000",
                "timestamp.delay.interval.ms":"1000",
                "validate.non.null":"false",
                "quote.sql.identifiers":"never",
                "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
                "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
                "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
                "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
                "plugin.path":"/opt/confluent/share/java,/opt/confluent/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc"
            }
        }'
         

        #
        sleep infinity


  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.0.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:6.0.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true
    networks:
      - syncNetwork      

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.0.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
    networks:
      - syncNetwork            
networks:
  syncNetwork:
    external: true

volumes:
    vpg_nms:
    vpg_mgr:
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what issues you are having copying the kafka and connect services.

But do so, and for Kafka2, you can use the same ZK container, but it needs a new chroot

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181/kafka2'
```

Then in the second connect image, you can modify `CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` and its advertised name